# Bootstrap-select does not toggle "open" class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

Check it out please -> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1hzxrpmk/)

I downloaded the source from http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/, I really have no idea why it's not toggling "open" class of ".dropdown-toggle"
I can fix it by adding some messy scripts, but I prefer the plugin to work right.

the HTML:

```
<div class="number customdp">
<select class="simple-dropdown" name="number">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

does anybody have a solution ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It has a dependency on twitter bootstrap. Include their CSS ***and JavaScript*** files like so:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

See [**this updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1hzxrpmk/1/) with the CSS and JS included, and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: oh thanks, isn't there a way not to include the whole bootstrap plugin but only the script that's relative to dropdowns ?

Comment: That would take some searching to figure out where the dependency is. Are you not using bootstrap  for your site?

Comment: no. I just need the select box of it. its so complete and crossbrowser

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ -> Customize and choose the components you need.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. Even after having the references right, the dropdown didn't show on click. So I included the following code and it worked.

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
    $(".bootstrap-select").click(function () {
         $(this).addClass("open");
    });
  });
```

Comment: I had the same issue,and  you code helped in opening it, but now it won't close!

Comment: That should not happen as long as you are clicking outside the dropdown. Could you create a fiddle showing the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update. My actual problem was a missing reference to the Bootstrap JavaScript file. Once i added that it started with just the class name - click function was not needed - Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The correct order of dependencies did not solve the problem for me. I tried [DynoMyte's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38838798/4810382) solution. The code opens a dropdown, but do not close it. So I added a few more lines that fix this.

```
   $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
      $(".bootstrap-select").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("open");
      });
      $(document).click(function(){
        $(".bootstrap-select").removeClass("open");
      });
      $(".bootstrap-select").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue because `bootstrap.js` was included as well as `dropdown.js` from the bootstrap library. bootstrap.js already included all parts of dropdown.js.

It seems like in this situation, all event handlers were attached twice, resulting in toggling the dropdown twice on click - which results in closing it immediately after opening.

Answer (score 0):

For the best solution was to include all JS files at the bottom of the `body` with following order:

1. jQuery
2. Bootstrap
3. Bootstrap-select